# Problem with .map() in function to create tags,React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a function to create tags via .map. But it throws an error "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

My code:

```
let options=()=>{props.teamDate.map((e,i)=>
    <option key={i} value={e.phone} name={e.Name}>e.Name</option>
)};
return (
    <section>
       <select>
          {options}
        </select>
    </section>
);
```

sample data from teamDate:

```
[{
        id: 1,
        Name: "text ",
        SecondName: "text",
        Phone: "text",
        Mail: "text",
    },{
        id: 2,
        Name: "text ",
        SecondName: "text",
        Phone: "text",
        Mail: "text",
    }
  ]
```

Comment: `options` is the function itself. I'm guessing you meant to use `options()` and `return` the array from your arrow function...

Comment: You are not calling the `options` function. `{options}` should be `{options()}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your options function to an object:

```
let options=data.map((e,i)=>
    <option key={i} value={e.phone} name={e.Name}>e.Name</option>
);
```

This was you can call your options as:

```
{options}
```

check the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@saadqbal/f3e4cd

Comment: The easiest way when you are using map function on array.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your calling parentheses on options

```
let options= () => props.teamDate.map((e,i)=>
    <option key={i} value={e.phone} name={e.Name}>e.Name</option>
);

return (
    <section>
       <select>
          {options()}
        </select>
    </section>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to do:

```
<section>
  <select>
    {props.teamDate.map(({ id, Name, Phone }) => (
      <option key={id} value={Phone} name={Name}>
        {Name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
</section>
```

Notice the use of `id`, and rendering `{Name}` instead of the string "e.Name"